# Wait for loop ending end execute second func

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions:

```
function parseFriends_new(range) {
var xml = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        var params = "gwt.requested=" + gwtHash + "&refId=search-d-" + Date.now() + "&d.sq=&d.o=" + range + "&d.d=d.in";
        xml.open("POST", "/dk?cmd=FriendsSearch", true);
        xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xml.setRequestHeader('TKN', TKN);
        xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (4 == xml.readyState && 200 == xml.status) {

            }
        }
        xml.send(params);
}
function postNoteAndTag(friendsList, repostId, trashText) {...}
```

I need to execute `postNoteAndTag` after `parseFriends_new`

```
for (var i = 0, range = 0; i < 20; i++, range += 10)
{
    parseFriends_new(range);
}
//wait for loop and then execute next code
postNoteAndTag(friendsList, repostId, trashText);
```

How to do this?

Comment: A for... loop is a blocking control structure. It already "waits" for the loop to be over before executing code below the loop. The only exception is if the function `parseFriends` does something asynchronous, like an AJAX request. If that's the case, then you'll have to implement some form of callback that you pass to the last call.

Comment: Is `parseFriends_new` async?

Comment: Then you will have to modify its signature so that it works with callbacks or even better promises (http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/).

Comment: The question is not tagged with jQuery, so that doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: @Chris: Promises are indeed the solution, they aren't tied to jQuery. http://promisesaplus.com/implementations

Comment: Promises are great, but the jquery api for promises isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Since `parseFriends_new` is asynchronous you might need to modify it so that it works with callbacks:

```
function parseFriends_new(range, done) {
    var xml = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    var params = "gwt.requested=" + gwtHash + "&refId=search-d-" + Date.now() + "&d.sq=&d.o=" + range + "&d.d=d.in";
    xml.open("POST", "/dk?cmd=FriendsSearch", true);
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xml.setRequestHeader('TKN', TKN);
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (4 == xml.readyState && 200 == xml.status) {
        }

        // The AJAX request finished => we can invoke the callback.
        // you could also pass it some result if needed
        done();
    }
    xml.send(params);
}
```

and then:

```
// We've got 20 AJAX requests to make at total
var count = 20;
for (var i = 0, range = 0; i < count; i++, range += 10) {
    parseFriends_new(range, function() {
        --count;
        if (count <= 0) {
            // All AJAX requests have finished executing
            // you can now do whatever you intended to do:
            postNoteAndTag(friendsList, repostId, trashText);
        }
    });
}
```

Bear in mind though that this is an absolutely bad practice to be hammering your web server with so many requests in a burst. It's bad for your server, it's bad for the client, it's bad for the TCP/IP.

A much better solution is to send a single AJAX request to the server with all the payload. It's far more efficient to send one large AJAX request than multiple small. Of course you might need to adapt your server side script to be able to process the request.